# ImageFieldFile object has no attribute startswith

Tags: django, django-models

Using the [django-storages package](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) S3 on the delete signal I'm trying to delete the image from S3 I have tried the following (see below) but get the error...

**'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'startswith'**

```
def product_pre_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Sent at the beginning of a product delete() method product queryset's delete() method.
    """
    default_storage.delete(instance.qr_image)

models.signals.pre_delete.connect(product_pre_delete, sender=Product)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, django-storages will only delete the file when the object itself is deleted (scroll down to the section on delete) https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html?highlight=delete

If you want to keep the object, but delete the file, you'll probably have to handle that yourself using [Boto](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/), which is the underlying library used by django-storages when working with S3.

Comment: Ok I assumed I would have to delete the object my bad. however it does not seem to delete the file when the object is deleted tho is this default?

Comment: It won't delete the file if there are other objects using it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this issue as well and found that the **'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'startswith'** error is thrown because you are using the file object rather then file.name.  Using the object works locally, but not with AWS.  The below code should work as I was able to successfully delete a file that is still associated with an object.

```
default_storage.delete(instance.qr_image.name)
```